# Custom View in TableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, view

I am new to swift and below is the problem that I faced. I have a tableview and one of the cell is customCell which loads custom view. No crashes but the constraints and background color for table cell are not displaying. Please refer to code below

```
    let data = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange", "Grape"]
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var customView: CustomView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        customView.myLabel.text = "Hey hey"
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 3 {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell()}

//            cell.layoutSubviews()
//            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }


    }
}


Custom View:
class CustomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    let kCONTENT_XIB_NAME = "CustomView"
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(kCONTENT_XIB_NAME, owner: self, options: nil)
        contentView.fixInView(self)
    }

}

extension UIView
{
    func fixInView(_ container: UIView!) -> Void{
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        self.frame = container.frame;
        container.addSubview(self);
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: container, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}

Custom Tablecell:
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellContentView: CustomView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        cellContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

[image]

When I run the app below is the screenshot how it displays enter image description here

[image]

Issue 1: Row 3 is customview whose background should be blue as set in Custom cell class

Issue 2: In my `ViewController`, even after setting background color as green why is it not displaying that color. "Orange" is used in storyboard while creating view

Issue 3: If I have more dynamic controls in view, how the cell height be set.

Please advice. I'm struck here

Comment: Your custom cell is in tableview so no need to write register method for custom cell.

Comment: ive registered and app is running fine. But layouts are not fitting as expected

Comment: Have u used ‘heightForRow’ method?

Comment: i tried giving automatic dimension since my view layout is dynamic but it doesn work

Comment: Plz add image of your custom view

Comment: Plus in order to work auto height, u have to give each view top and bottom constraints.

Comment: orange "hey hey" message thats loaded via custom view. Im expecting same to be loaded at indexpath 3

Comment: reason is it always returning UITableViewCell not your custom cell. make sure your custom cell inherited to uitableview cell and also in your UITableView you had set your reusable identifier correctly.

Comment: it is returning custom cell. Indexpath at 3 is custom cell. But ive set its background color to green and it is not visible. thats my question

Answer (score 0):

Add your `cellContentView` in cell `contentview`

```
Custom Tablecell:
  class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellContentView: CustomView!

      override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Initialization code
        contentView.addSubview(cellContentView) // add this line
        cellContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```